# Providing a default read only value in kendo text area,which should be able to append user entered value

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, textarea, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using kendo UI for angular(currently on version 9). I am looking to have a text area which has some default value in it.
Default value should be un-editable/read-only, but the text area should still accept input from user and append the user input to existing default value.
It's like to have a permanent placeholder which can append user input values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a `<fieldset>` ?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <fieldset>
        <legend>{{readonlyPreface}}</legend>
        <textarea
          kendoTextArea           
          (valueChange)="forcedPreface($event)"
        >{{myTextArea}}</textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <hr>
        Combined: <textarea readonly>{{combined}}</textarea>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  combined: string;

  readonlyPreface = "Diagnosis: ";

  forcedPreface(event) {
    this.combined = this.readonlyPreface + event;
  }
}
```